# Dynamically recreate smaller css files on the fly

Tags: php, css

I have searched Stack Overflow and found nothing about this. So here it goes

I was wondering if anyone has created server side script (PHP preferred) that can determine what css rules are required for a page to render. Something that would cross reference the HTML with a set group of css files and recreate a lighter version for a specific page.

Since Googles Update and the importance to render blocking scripts/CSS and to lighten the load I think this would be an awesome script.

Comment: You do realize that 1 stylesheet for the entire site is better than multiple stylesheets all over the site, because of browser cache. Why would you need a lighter stylesheet page by page? That would require the server to calculate the request each time a page loads, create a new file, and then serve that file. How is this helpful to the end user? You want your stylesheet cached for load time.

Comment: I agree with @SeanStopnik. In addition: finding out which rules "are required" is an impossible task! What does that mean? What about dynamic content?

Comment: Similar to caching technics could create the file once and then just search if exists and then add that file. I have a site that has a large css file that pagespeed is always saying it is render blocking. Annoys the sheit out of me. similar to Jquery that is needed throughout the site and is always flagged as a render blocking source. So thought if I had smaller css files to download it would improve page speed. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: My guess is your stylesheet is full of bloat and 'bad practices'. The answer isn't to split up stylesheets per page, but rather take a good look at your site wide CSS and rewrite accordingly. Modularize you CSS. Create reusable components. This will greatly reduce a large stylesheet.

Comment: Full of bloat and bad practices was not a smart remark. know your audience and don't assume if you don't know them Sean. The blocking css is the bootstrap.min.css.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether the tool you're asking for exists in its "pure form". The closest thing I'm aware of are unused css removal tools [like this one](https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss). Such tools would accept a css file and a number of html files and remove css rules, that are not used.

Please not that the tool I've linked is designed to be used at *build time*, not *run time*. That means you would want to use it to get rid of unused css before/when you deploy your website, not on every request.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't come across such a script but implementing one is not that complicated.  My thoughts to implement would be like below:

- You could cache the main css declarations in a server-side php array like

  ```
  $css = array(".tag1"=>array(
                              "width: 10px;",
                               "height:10px;"
                              ),
               "#tag2"=>array(
                              "position:relative;",
                              "float:fixed;"
                              )
               );
  ```
- Declare a php array of css tags used in the file at the top of the page (like how you do for validation) like `$cssused = array(".tag1", "#tag2");`
- On page load, compare the two arrays (like `in_array($cssused, $css)` or `array_key_exists('#tag2", $css)`) and load the css declarations for the tags that match in the main css array inside the `<style>...</style>` tags.
- Whenever you make changes in the file, you have to just add/edit those in the `$cssused` array.

Comment: I found this and it seems to be a great tool for I dentifying css need for each page: http://paul.kinlan.me/detecting-critical-above-the-fold-css/